# How to clear the Terminal screen in Swift?

Tags: swift, macos, command-line, terminal

I am writing a BASIC Interpreter for the Command Line in Swift 2, and I cannot find a way to implement the simple command, CLS (clear all text from the Terminal.) Should I simply print spaces in a loop, or is there a function I'm not aware of that would clear the Terminal screen?

Comment: How about `system("clear")` or similar (e.g. with `popen`)? Alternatively, simulate the pressing of Ctrl-L with AppleScript (or `osascript` through the command line)

Comment: How about http://linux.die.net/man/3/curs_clear ?

Comment: @Arc676 Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you. Out of curiosity, where did you learn of this command?

Comment: Which command? `osascript`?

Comment: Better than hard-coding - [Ncurses with Swift on Linux](http://dev.iachieved.it/iachievedit/ncurses-with-swift-on-linux/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the built-in `clear` command either with `system`

```
system("clear")
```

or `popen` (ask Google)

Alternatively, simulate the pressing of Ctrl+L using AppleScript via the command line:

```
osascript -e 'tell app "terminal" to tell app "system events" to keystroke "l" using {control down}'
```

EDIT: `system` is no longer available in newer verions of Swift. See [Rudolf Adamkovič's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36704070/2773311).

Answer (score 14):

You can use the following ANSI sequence:

```
print("\u{001B}[2J")
```

... where `\u{001B}` is `ESCAPE` and `[2J` is clear screen.

Comment: Only answer that worked for me. MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014) OS X El Capitan.

Comment: This works because `system` is unavailable in Swift 3.  I'll see what I can do to update my answer to use `posix_spawn` APIs or `NSTask`.

Comment: Any idea why when I use this it prints `[2J` instead of clearing?

Comment: @BenOng I've discovered that this does work in a standard terminal window, but prints "[2J" if you are using the console built into Xcode. The Xcode terminal is also unable to print colors properly, so I'm guessing it's just a general ANSI interpretation problem when running your console app from the IDE.
Try archiving your build and running it standalone.

Comment: it only prints [2J

Comment: Any idea how to go to first line as well? this clears the screen but new prints appear in the middle of terminal while the top is empty

Answer (score 2):

**This answer applies to Swift 2.1 or earlier only**

To elaborate on [Arc676's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33448453/2415822):

The `system` command is imported into Swift via the Darwin module on Mac platforms (with other C APIs).  On Linux, Glibc replaces Darwin for bridging low-level C APIs to Swift.

```
import Glibc

// ...

system("clear")
```

Or, if the `system` call is ambiguous, explicitly call Glibc's `system` (or Darwin on Mac platforms):

```
import Glibc

// ...

Glibc.system("clear")
```

Comment: With Swift 3 I am getting `"system" is unavailable in Swift: Use posix_spawn APIs or NSTask instead`

Answer (score 1):

This code makes a synchronous call to the built-in `clear` command. This won't cause problem with `readLine()` since it prints the escape sequence returned by `clear` using Swift's `print()` function

```
var cls = Process()
var out = Pipe()
cls.launchPath = "/usr/bin/clear"
cls.standardOutput = out
cls.launch()
cls.waitUntilExit()
        print (String(data: out.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile(), encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) ?? "")
```

Comment: Just to be clear, this works in terminal. But if you try it to clear console screen inside Xcode, it gives `TERM environment variable not set.`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in Swift 3.1

```
var clearScreen = Process()
clearScreen.launchPath = "/usr/bin/clear"
clearScreen.arguments = []
clearScreen.launch()
clearScreen.waitUntilExit()
```

You can create a function with a callback like this

```
func clearScreen(completion:@escaping (Bool) -> () ) {
        let clearScreen = Process()
        clearScreen.launchPath = "/usr/bin/clear"
        clearScreen.arguments = []
        clearScreen.terminationHandler = { task in completion(true) }
        clearScreen.launch()
        clearScreen.waitUntilExit()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

if you are inside the REPL just type

> :shell clear