# Swift 3 equivalent of "system()" from C++

Tags: swift, terminal

I'm looking to write a command line program, and one thing I used a lot in C++ was `system("clear");` to clear the screen of the terminal window. I can use print("\u{001B}[2J") to clear the screen, but I still would like to be able to have my program "type" into the terminal.

Comment: Hope [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33448353/how-to-clear-the-terminal-screen-in-swift) helps

Comment: If you're using Swift 3, `system` will be unavailable. You will need to use the `posix_spawn` APIs or `NSTask`.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `Process` from Foundation:

```
import Foundation

func clear() {
    let p = Process()
    p.launchPath = "/usr/bin/clear"
    p.launch()
}

clear()
```

Comment: I tried this, but when I ran the program, the first time I had a readLine() the program crashed immediately.